# Google Ads PPC Campaign & EU Deadline on January 16, 2024

Tags: google-ads

I am a sole proprietor selling a product through my website, and I am based in Asia. I run a basic HTML site and advertise it globally (including Europe) via a PPC campaign on my personal Google Ads account. I only use Display and Search ads campaigns.

Recently, I came across the following news articles:

1. https://searchengineland.com/google-urgent-steps-advertisers-eu-436687
2. https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/13554020?hl=en&ref_topic=10924967&sjid=6888106173792681639-AP

Despite conducting numerous searches online, I am still unsure if the above information applies to me, as the process seems to be quite complex. However, I need my Pay Per Click campaign to have a presence in Europe, as I am also exporting my product there.

I do not use Google AdSense, AdMob, or Google Ad Manager. I simply use my personal Google Adwords account for the PPC campaign. Does the January 16, 2024 EU deadline apply to me? Should I do something or I can safely ignore this?